# how to change the app.config file settings

Tags: c#, wpf

how to change the app.config file settings
 my app.com is

```
   <configuration>
     <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" />
        <section name="Chat.Properties.Settings"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <Chat.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Chat_WebReference_WebService1" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://localhost/logs/abc.asmx</value>
            </setting>
        </Chat.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

i want  edit  value
**http://localhost/logs/abc.asmx**

Comment: Im assuming you want to do this at runtime?

Comment: Your app.config file is invalid. `<sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" />` U're already closed this tag. Why are cosing it again  `</sectionGroup>` at line 5 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is set up correctly, you should be able to use `Properties.Settings.Default`:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Chat_WebReference_WebService1 = "new value";
```

If you want to persist back to the file, don't forget to save:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

---

**Edit** The settings have to be placed under `userSettings` or the above will throw an error.

```
<userSettings>
    <Chat.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="Chat_WebReference_WebService1" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://localhost/logs/abc.asmx</value>
        </setting>
    </Chat.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

Comment: Properties.Settings.Default.Chat_WebReference_WebService1 = "new value"; here  showing error   ** cannot assigned read only**

Comment: @Amop my mistake -- they need to go under `userSettings` or they'll be read only at runtime.